# Is there a way to disable the AGPL message in iTextSharp 5.5.11

Tags: c#, itext

I've inherited some code that uses iTextSharp 5.5.11 in a .NET console application. It opens and scans all the pdfs in a folder and extracts a couple of strings (a workorder number and a closed date). It then writes these to a text file. It works great. However, once it hits 10,000 pdfs it begins displaying the "You are using iText under the AGPL" message. I've found how to disable the message in iText, but I'm wondering if there's a way to disable it in iTextSharp 5.5.11?

relevant code:

```
string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(inputDir, "*.pdf");
foreach(string pdfFile in pdfFiles)
{
    PdfReader reader = reader = new PdfReader(new RandomAccessFileOrArray(pdfFile, true), null);
    // rest of code
}
```

Comment: The counter is in https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/log/DefaultCounter.cs#L80, NOP that and rebuild the library? You can also follow the reference for Version and replace/remove any indication of the AGPL string which trigger the messages.

Comment: why do you want to disable the message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched and cannot find a way to disable the message in iTextSharp, as there is in iText. So I will answer "no".